# How to create app which can be launched with dialpad

Tags: android

I wanted to know how can i launch my android app with some code from Dialpad. Like if you
    *#*#3214789650#*#*
from your galaxy it launches angryGps application.
How to implement that?

Thanks.

Comment: Never tried this but, I think, this will be done using some Broadcast receiver.

Comment: add * after every # in above number

Comment: @awais you have try using` ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @noli can you show some example or hint ? thanks

Comment: @imrankhan nice but if you try above code you don't actually press the green call button, the application is started as you hit last star. Any other suggestion? though i will let you know after implementing it with the broadcastreceiver u mentioned. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this.use Broadcast Receivers to listen outgoing call number:

**Manifest.xml**

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>


<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver"> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

**OutgoingCallReceiver.java**

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (null == bundle)
            return;
        // outgoingNumber=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
       //START APPLICATION HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, but is there a way to prevent the dial pad from attempting to dial this "phone number" after your `BroadcastReceiver` is called?

Comment: @TonythePony yes in your receiver call this: setResultData(null);

Comment: Great, but I believe this only works for ordered broadcasts, correct?

Comment: @TonythePony yes i think from the way its working as it is returning some result set.

Comment: @imrankhan Its a work around but it will do the trick, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is part of contacts application and Although its very likely that the implementation is same for every manufacturer but i am not sure about this.

The intent for starting a new activity is passed by the function **handleSecretCode** in the file [SpecialCharSequenceMgr](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Contacts/src/com/android/contacts/SpecialCharSequenceMgr.java). The code snippet is

```
    static boolean handleSecretCode(Context context, String input) {

    // Secret codes are in the form *#*#<code>#*#*

    int len = input.length();

    if (len > 8 && input.startsWith("*#*#") && input.endsWith("#*#*")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.SECRET_CODE_ACTION,
                Uri.parse("android_secret_code://" + input.substring(4, len - 4)));
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

What you need to do is to register broadcast receiver for the intent action **Intents.SECRET_CODE_ACTION** and the uri **android_secret_code://"code"** and in the broadcast receiver you can launch your application.

Also you can see how some applications are already implementing, One of the code that works on emulator is * #* #4636 #* #*.

Comment: For an example you can see [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/TestingSettingsBroadcastReceiver.java). And for the manifest file [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml). Hope it helps you.