# How can I develop an app which will not appear in launching menu of android

Tags: android

How i can develop an app which will not appear in launching menu (neither its icon nor launcher).
I will launch it by some other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How i can develop an app which will not appear in launching menu (neither its icon nor launcher)

Do not have any activities with an `<intent-filter>` for the `MAIN` action and `LAUNCHER` category.

> I will launch it by some other ways.

On Android 3.1+, such "other ways" may not work. The user has to manually launch one of your activities for anything else of your app to work (e.g., `BroadcastReceiver`).

Comment: i mean is there some way of hiding android app icon? if i set android:enable=false; the application is installed but i can't launch it with intents. But it is installed and appears in manage applications.

Comment: @AwaisAkhtar: "i mean is there some way of hiding android app icon?" -- please re-read my answer. "if i set android:enable=false" -- I did not mention this in my answer, which you can tell if you would re-read my answer. "But it is installed and appears in manage applications" -- that cannot be hidden, except by not having the app on the device in the first place.

Comment: any insight on how those test applications exists: AngryGps or phone info test launched by *#*#4636#*#*  thanks

Comment: @AwaisAkhtar: You already asked that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226995/how-to-create-app-which-can-be-launched-with-dialpad

Comment: ah ok i got it. sorry forget about that intent-filter thing. Thanks